# How to include millisecond in syslogs?

Tags: log, time, syslog, rsyslog

I have configured `rsyslog.conf` file in `/etc` to include my own logs as `syslogs` in a file at `/var/logs`.

But after opening the file I got this:

```
Jun 5 10:09:09 lab-Altos-G330-Mk2 slog[19689]: Hello1
Jun 5 10:09:09 lab-Altos-G330-Mk2 slog[19689]: Hello2
```

Here, the `timestamp` only has second resolution.  I want to know how to configure `rsyslog` to display milliseconds also?

Answer (score 10):

By default, `rsyslog` uses traditional timestamp, which in `date` command's format would be:

```
%b %d %H:%M:%S
```

This is enabled by the following line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

To enable high precision timestamping, comment out the line:

```
# $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

which will make `rsyslog` timestamping in the RFC 3339 format.

---

The RFC 3339 format can be simulated by the `date` command:

```
% date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z'
2016-06-05T18:27:58.721607+06:00
```

Or even shorter:

```
% date '+%FT%T.%6N%:z'      
2016-06-05T18:29:32.569776+06:00
```

Or using the native `--rfc-3399` option:

```
% date --rfc-3339=ns
2016-06-05 18:31:50.897557592+06:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.,but now I am getting microseconds..,can I configure rfc 3339 to give me milliseconds..?

Comment: @user3767070 Ummm, i don't see anything native in `rsyslog`..You need to parse the logs manually i am afraid..

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, replace

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

with:

```
$template CustomFormat,"%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339% %timegenerated:12:24:date-rfc3339% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate CustomFormat
```

Now, if you `logger test && tail -1 /var/log/syslog`, you'd get:

```
2020-08-10 18:28:49.5397 user: test
```

Comment: The syntax is documented at https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/property_replacer.html